# How to optimize images loaded into site from instagram?

Tags: magento-1.9, slider

I am currently working on a website loaded with multiple social media items.  I have optimized the js, css and other files.  My current problem is that there is an instagram slider that takes the pictures from instagram and it slows down the loading of the site.  The images are updated a couple of times a week and we cant have static pictures.  How do I work on this to improve the loading speed of the slider?  Do I load it only after the whole page is loaded or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: images are updated a couple of times a week??  You are loading Instagram images from magento or each time requesting to Instagram???  Can use ajax after page load

Comment: its a fashion shop.  People upload their pictures to show off.  The latest 20 images are then shown in the slider.  Ajax is already used to load the slider.  The images are in a cdn that is from instagram.  GT metrix and pingdom both say the images are too slow to load.

Comment: Use lazy load best option.
We have implemented that in our Magento 2 instagram plugin https://magecomp.com/magento-2-instagram-integration-pro.html